# Creating a query that filters by activities' [email|phonecall|letter] recipient using CRM 4.0 SDK

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to retrieve a list of all activities to a contact (not just regarding) using the CRM SDK.
When ever I try to filter on 'to'  (type of partylist) I get an error.

**{"Instance validation error: '49' is not a valid value for Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Query.ConditionOperator."}**

So I guess the question is...
How do I filter on a partylist with the CRM 4 SDK query?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your QueryExpression ? What ConditionOperator did you use ? Apparently there are some values that are in the SDK DLLs and offered through IntelliSense but not actually accepted by the CRM web service.